# How to adjust the arrow size in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-3, sketchapp

How to adjust the arrow size, not the thickness
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4lAy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no specific setting.

I would recommend you to work with a line and an element such a triangle to have the same effect with controllable sizes.
You can also transform this combination of line and triangle in a symbol and replicate through out your artwork.

Comment: I found a plugin that could help you: https://github.com/teeerevor/loose-sketch-plugin